# How to add dependencies to CompositeApplicationProject?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Project pom editor doesn't show any dependencies in CompositeApplicationProject, except Custom Mediator Project. Rest of project (dependencies) like ESB Config Project, DSS Project,  in same eclipse workspace are invisible.

I download old release of WsoTooling 3.8.0 and that one able add to CompositeApplicationProject dependency Registry Project only.

Is it possible manually manage dependencies(projects) in CompositeApplicationProject ?

Comment: Eventually after spending hours find out. WsoTooling using eclipse api to track changes in workspace (creating new entities projects and so on). It is not possible to copy file into workspace or project. It must be created using developer studio.

Comment: How can i create such a file for projects still exsiting and shared via SVN?

Comment: I not sure, but i think there is somthing like import project or files.

Comment: I imported my samples over Project Explorer -> Import -> wso2 projects. I got all my projects in the explorer correctly displayed, but in the CompositeApplication i just see my custom mediator project to add it to the CompositeApplication. So my problem is not solved jet. But thanks for your reply @simar

Comment: Yeah. It exactly same problem I did describe in topic. Project import is treated as just a common java or maven project not a composite application. Result elements of synapse are not recognized. Currently only way is to create template project and import it as wso project.

Comment: These something like registry that can be used to share definitions of synapse elements. https://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/